# How to assign matrix elements randomly

Tags: matlab, matrix

In Matlab, I would like to know how to assign values inside a matrix randomly for any given size matrix?

For example:

```
Enter non-zero elements in 3*3 matrix? 3

      1
      4
      7
```

These elements are to be randomly placed in 3*3 matrix and the remaining 6 elements become zero.

In general, for some number of non-zero elements we enter in a matrix, the remaining elements in the matrix become zero.

How do I write the code in Matlab for the above example? I have to give as input the number of non-zero elements and assign the input values randomly inside the matrix without specifying any particular row or column.

Comment: I would like to help edit this question to make it more clear for future viewers with similar problems, but I'm not sure what the sentance "No non-zero element we enter in a matrix remaining element in matrix becomes zero." means. Can you maybe describe it a bit more? Maybe show an example matrix? I am happy to help with English grammar.

Comment: @2cents *sorry* it is number of non-zeros

Comment: I edited the post to clarify the sentence. If you feel it doesn't represent what you were trying to say, feel free to roll back or let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very simple to do using [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) and [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511)

```
V = [1,4,7];
M = zeros(3);
M(randperm(numel(M), numel(V))) = V
```

If you have an old version of Matlab (see comments, this also applies if you're using Octave) then you can try:

```
V = [1,4,7];
M = zeros(3);
I = randperm(numel(M));
M(I(1:numel(V))) = V
```

Comment: i am getting error -Error using ==> randperm
Too many input arguments. **Thank u**

Comment: @user3789221 - You are most likely using an older version of MATLAB where `randperm` only accepted 1 argument.  To be precise, the two argument form of `randperm` was only introduced in `R2012a`.  To mimic what Dan has programmed, you can split it up into two statements:  `M2 = randperm(numel(M)); M(M2(1:numel(V))) = V;`

Comment: @user3789221 Glad it helped. Please make sure you read through the links I posted to understand how it works.